# Use winexe and powershell to configure some service on a Windows

Tags: linux, windows, centos, powershell

I'm making a script to configure SNMP on a Windows.
This script had to be launched from a Centos OS.

I'm quite a zero in Windows scripting so i found a PSscript on the Internet :

https://community.whatsupgold.com/library/powershellscripts/installandconfiguresnmpwithpowershell

I need to launch this PSscript from a command like :

```
winexe -U USER%PWD //IP "powershell -Command & {SCRIPT.PS1}"
```

Can i make it with the PSscript on my Centos os ? (I don't think so)

Did you know the exact form to launch a PSscript from Winexe ?

Thank's for reading and maybe helping me =)

Comment: take a look at the following link: http://hindenes.com/trondsworking/2012/05/17/run-powershell-through-ssh/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you !
I answer if someone need it :

```
winexe -U administrateur%$PWD //$IP "powershell -Command & {(c:\User\administrateur\powershell.ps1)}"
```

This will launch the PSscript "powershell.ps1" on the remote server.